# Is there a configuration to save Job data into database in Spring Boot Quartz when HikariCP auto commit is false

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp, quartz

We have jhipster Spring boot application. It uses Hikari CP with auto commit set to false. Looks like this is part of this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9261). I am trying to integrate Quartz with Spring using spring-boot-starter-quartz. Problem is that job details are not saving into db If the HikariCP auto commit set to false.

I tried dontSetAutoCommitFalse of quarts with both true & false without success.

```
spring:
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          threadPool:
            threadCount: 5
          jobStore:
            #dontSetAutoCommitFalse: false
            class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
```

I am looking for way to make Quartz persistence work with HikariCP auto commit false.

Comment: did you figure out how to do it ?